# Facebook Comments plugin - How to remove Top Section (Comments and Sort by)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to remove top section only...

I didn't find any configuration related to remove or hide this section…

I followed this docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

[image]

Comment: _“I didn't find any configuration related to remove or hide this section…”_ - there isn’t any.

Comment: there is anyway to remove this section without hacking the Facebook policies

Comment: The actual policy on using those social plugins, is that you not try to change anything about their look&feel, other than what the options/parameters provided by Facebook allow for. And since this renders as a 3rd-party iframe, you can not format anything _inside_ using your own CSS, so at most you could try and hide the upper part of the iframe (clipping, or hide it _behind_ something else.)

Comment: ok thank you, i will try to use custom css to make it smaller